# ¿Comparar valores?

Tags: laravel

Tratare de ser breve, no se si algo así es posible, quiero editar los valores de una tabla, lo cual se que se hace con un update, pero quiero que para permitir editar dichos valores compare los valores que están almacenados, con los nuevos, y de ser iguale los almacene, de lo contrario no permita hacerlo. 
Explico la razón; voy a almacenar datos de una transacción, pero el administrador debe autorizar dicha transacción, pero para poder autorizar debería poder ingresar el número de transacción, y sí es igual entonces se almacena y se permite la autorización, de ser distinto entonces se niega.

Comment: Seria como verificar primero con un select que exista por ej: transaction_id y luego hacer un update de ese registro.  (obviamente hay que validar la autorización correspondiente)

Answer (score 0):

Nose si entendí bien, pero lo que podrías hacer es buscar la transacción en base a los dígitos que ingrese el usuario, en caso de que exista esa transacción la actualizas, usando eloquent seria algo asi..

```
// Id es el id de transacción que ingreso el usuario, en caso de no querer buscar por id podes usar el metodo find..
$data = App\SomeModel::findOrFail($id);


// Si usas el metodo findOrFail ya te aseguras de que la transaccion existe, pero de todas formas poder usar un if

if (data)
{
   // actualizas los datos..
}
```